# How to create a query using a view

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I use the view I created to get different data outputs.  I have created the view VJobCustomerLaborCost.  This view gives each job for each customer with total of labor cost for each job.  I need to get each customer with total labor cost for each customer.  I have given the View and sample outputs.

```
GO
CREATE VIEW VJobCustomerLaborCost
AS
SELECT DISTINCT
     TJ.intJobID
    ,TJ.strJobDescription
    ,TC.intCustomerID
    ,TC.strLastName + ', ' + TC.strFirstName AS strCustomerName
    ,SUM(TJE.intHoursWorked * TE.monHourlyRate) AS monTotalLaborCost
FROM    
     TJobs          AS TJ
    ,TJobCustomers  AS TJC
    ,TCustomers     AS TC
    ,TJobEmployees  AS TJE
    ,TEmployees     AS TE
WHERE
        TJ.intJobID         =   TJC.intJobID
    AND TJC.intCustomerID   =   TC.intCustomerID
    AND TJ.intCustomerID    =   TJC.intCustomerID
    AND TJE.intJobID        =   TJ.intJobID
GROUP BY
     TJ.intJobID
    ,TJ.strJobDescription
    ,TC.intCustomerID
    ,TC.strLastName
    ,TC.strFirstName
GO
```

This is the output from my view. This gives me all customers and each jobs total labor cost

```
 intJobID      strJobDescription         intCustomerID       strCustomerName       monTotalLaborCost
----------- ------------------------- -------------------  -----------------    ---------------------
1           Kitchen Remodel                 1             Belcher, Bob             8740.00
8           Basement Remodel                1             Belcher, Bob             13300.00
9           Bathroom Remodel                1             Belcher, Bob             12065.00
10          Roof Replacement                1             Belcher, Bob              3325.00
11          Living Room Remodel             1             Belcher, Bob                0.00
3           Bedroom Remodel                 3             Parker, Peter             3800.00
6           Roof Replacement                3             Parker, Peter               0.00
7           Basement Remodel                3             Parker, Peter             1710.00
4           Bedroom Remodel                 4             Solo, Hans                2850.00
5           Basement Remodel                2             Stark, Tony                  0.00
```

What I need is to use the View created to get total labor cost for each customer.  So output would be

```
   intCustomerID       strCustomerName       monTotalLaborCost
 -------------------  -----------------    ---------------------
    1               Belcher, Bob                37,430
    3               Parker, Peter               5,510
    4               Solo, Hans                  2,850
    2               Stark, Tony                 0.00
```

How do I use the above view to get this output?

Comment: If you've already crunched the data by grouping it in a view, you've lost data, so you can't get a different analysis if it requires data from the table that you can no longer see. However, in this instance, it sounds like you just want to sum up the costs per customer, so just group by customer ID and `SUM` the costs.

Comment: As I suggested in your previous post....and provided an example...you REALLY need to stop using this antiquated join syntax. As you said you are still learning. It is not too late to unlearn this poor syntax that your professor gave you.

Comment: I don't disagree but this is how he wants us to turn in the work. He says we will switch over to the new syntax in the next course.  I have been playing around with it so I can get used to using the new syntax.  Thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need just to group and sum your data:

```
select 
    intCustomerID, 
    strCustomerName, 
    sum(monTotalLaborCost) as monTotalLaborCost
from VJobCustomerLaborCost
group by intCustomerID, strCustomerName
```

Comment: Wow that was painless. I was way over thinking it.  Thanks!